# Reference requests for the philosophical analysis of sentences

Tags: reference-request, linguistics

I am looking for texts that analyze the concept of sentences from a philosophical perspective. I know there is a Stanford Encyclopedia of Philosophy article on propositions, but that is not exactly what I am looking for. I am looking for texts that define what a sentence is, compares and contrasts sentences with propositions, and other philosophical issues regarding sentences.

Comment: If you mean analysis of sentences in the sense of syntax as compared with propositions, then perhaps you need to search for the production rules of grammar of a language...

Comment: Not a book but maybe usefull : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sVJpbZdiT84

Comment: Sybil Wolfram, Philosophcal Logic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you looked into the [Oxford Handbook of Philosophy of Language](https://academic.oup.com/edited-volume/38631?login=false)?

There are many texts that discuss what you describe in various degrees of rigor. They mostly involve very specific positions on these points. Therefore, I would suggest a reliable source that discusses them from a more neutral point of view and introduces the different possible positions.

Otherwise, you will be stuck with *one* definition and would not be able to critically discuss/think about it.

Answer (score 0):

In the mid-1960s, California public schools taught something called *language arts* which involved breaking sentences down into their component parts and stringing those parts together in a graph called a *diagram* that allowed each part of the sentence to be seen in both isolation and in the context of the original sentence- thereby reducing sentence structure into an instruction string that was like an algorithm. That was supposed to lay bare the relationship between different parts of a sentence, which was supposed to reveal *grammar*.

It was useless as a tool for teaching grammar and sentence structure and, like "new math", eventually went away.

Perhaps the practice of diagramming sentences might furnish you with some insights into the philosophical structure of sentences. It certainly wasn't useful for any other purpose.